# ORACLE Pro*C/C++ code not rounding up results

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I have a database table called `My_table` with a column called `timestamps`, which 
contains the following data.

```
12-May-19
12-Jun-09
12-Apr-08
```

When I convert this timestamp to since 1970 using this sql query:

```
SELECT (timestamps - to-date(197001010000, 'yyyymmddhhss)×864) from My_table;
```

It returns a rounded up integer like 1459600 as expected on the ORACLE SQLPLUS terminal. However, if I execute the same query in an ORACLE  Pro*C/C++ dynamic code which correctly set the data type as integer (selectda-T(i) = 2), it does not round up the results, it only truncate the results.

How can I get it to behave exactly the same as it is on the ORACLE SQLPLUS terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, if you [check the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_04dat.htm#i15640), Oracle says

> INTEGER ... On output, if the column value is a real number, Oracle truncates any fractional part.

So if you want your integer rounded, you have to do it yourself in the SQL, e.g.

```
SELECT round(timestamps - to-date(197001010000, 'yyyymmddhhss')×864) from My_table;
```

Comment: Please does this ORACLE truncation only occurs when excuting an pro*c/c++ code? Because on the SQLPLUS terminal it does round it up to the nearest integer.

Comment: Yes, it's the ProC precompiler which is truncating the integer. In SQLPlus the default number formatting can be configured with `SET NUMFORMAT`, but in ProC I don't think it can be modified.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, much appreciated.